# How to configure VIM Ale to use the Tidy linter for HTML?

Tags: vim, tidy, linter, vim-ale

I'm trying to configure the vim Ale plugin to use Tidy to lint HTML code.
I added to my `.vimrc` file:

```
 let g:ale_linters = {
 \   'css': ['csslint'],
 \   'html': ['tidy'],
 \   'javascript': ['eslint'],
 \   'php': [''],
 \   'python': ['flake8'],
 \}
```

I got the linters working for CSS, JavaScript, and Python, but not HTML.

`:ALEInfo` outputs:

```
Current Filetype: html
Available Linters: ['alex', 'fecs', 'htmlhint', 'proselint', 'stylelint', 'tidy', 'writegood']
Linter Aliases: 'writegood' -> ['write-good']

Enabled Linters: ['tidy']

. . . at the end of the information . . .

Command History: (executable check - success) tidy
```

It looks like the Tidy linter is available and configured, but I can't get it to work.  The html files seem to have no linting at all.

I am able to run Tidy successfully in the terminal:

```
> tidy test.html
line 1 column 1 - Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
line 1 column 1 - Warning: plain text isn't allowed in <head> elements
line 1 column 2 - Warning: discarding unexpected <html>
line 2 column 5 - Warning: <body> unexpected or duplicate quote mark
line 2 column 5 - Warning: discarding unexpected <body>
line 4 column 7 - Error: <bdy> is not recognized!
line 4 column 7 - Warning: discarding unexpected <bdy>
line 1 column 1 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
line 3 column 7 - Warning: trimming empty <p>
Info: Document content looks like HTML 3.2
8 warnings, 1 error were found!
```

How can I get Tidy to work with Ale in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to tell `vim` where to find the tidy executable, e.g., `tidy` on Linux, or `tidy.exe` on Windows.

In my case, I added this to my `vimrc`:

```
let g:ale_html_tidy_executable = "D://TidyHtml//tidy-5.6.0-vc14-64b//bin//tidy.exe"
```

In vim, to get Ale help for tidy: `:h ale-html-tidy`